# Extending IP-range

Tags: ip, dhcp-server

We have a problem with our IP-range. For the moment it is 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.254. Unfortunately it isn't enough anymore.

So we wanted to setup a whole new scope on our DHCP server 2008. We want to use all the IPs from 10.0.0.1 till 10.0.10.254 (or more).

At the beginning, we worked with subnet 255.255.255.0. Now we changed it to 255.255.0.0. (from C to B).

We made an distribution group that gives Ip's from 10.0.1.0 till 10.0.2.254 (10.0.0.1 till 10.0.0.254 is for reservations).

The DHCP-server works, it gives an IP in that range. Unfortunately the connection is restricted.

It seams that they can't access the router (who's static 10.0.0.254). What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you updated the subnet mask and any other applicable config on the router?

Comment: Just checking again.. I guess the problem should be there. Because the clients get the correct ip and correct subnet..

Comment: Router settings:
Local IP address 10.0.0.254
Subnet mask 255.255.0.0
Gateway 10.0.0.254
Local DNS 10.0.0.1

Comment: DHCP of router is disabled..

Comment: "from C to B" -- RFC1519 was published *22 years ago*.  It's time to move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the DHCP-server had a subnet of 255.255.255.0

After I changed that, It worked..